# How does java know what index to use

Tags: java, events, jbutton, actionlistener

I got a quick question, how does the following code know what index is pressed, what is confusing me is it adds an actionlistener to each button via a for loop, but when i press a button how can the program know whether index is either 1 or 5 since index is equal only to the for loops current index (if that doesnt make sense let me know, idk how to put this question into works correctly)

```
private void buttonEvtListeners(){
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        final int index = i;
        comp.buttons1[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(index < 3){
                    System.out.println("Save button index: " + index);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Panel Save button index: " + index);
                }
            }
        });
        comp.buttons2[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(index < 3){
                    System.out.println("Default button index: " + index);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Panel Default button index: " + index);
                }
            }
        });
        comp.buttons3[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(index < 3){
                    System.out.println("Undo button index: " + index);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Panel Undo button index: " + index);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous classes take a copy of the fields which they use. They even take a copy of `this` if there is one. (Called `this$0` by default) If you use the debugger or reflections you can see those values.  They are implicitly pass to the constructor of the class and made into final fields.  The fields it can access have to be `final` to simplify the usage.  In Java 8, closures can access fields which are effectively final i.e. they could have been made final.

Comment: your answer is better than mine :) +1

Comment: Oh ok, that makes much more sense! Thanks a bunch

Comment: One last thing, I thought final values aren't suppose to be incremented, why does final index get incremented if its final?

Comment: @Loligans It doesn't.  You are incrementing `i`